# Is there a way to continue from where the error occured instead of repeating?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, try-catch, valueerror

I have this loop

```
for i in range(branches):
    count += 1
    while True:
        try:
            computer = int(input('{} {} :'.format("Enter number of books for computer of branch", count)))
            bookCount.append(computer)
            physics = int(input('{} {} :'.format("Enter number of books for phsyics of branch", count)))
            bookCount.append(physics)
            chemistry = int(input('{} {} :'.format("Enter number of books for chemistry of branch", count)))
            bookCount.append(chemistry)
            biology = int(input('{} {} :'.format("Enter number of books for biology of branch", count)))
            bookCount.append(biology)
            arts = int(input('{} {} :'.format("Enter number of books for arts of branch", count)))
            bookCount.append(arts)
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be a number")
            continue
        if computer < 1:
            print("Number must be at least 1")
        else:
            break
```

If i enter say "Hello" instead of an int, the try except will catch the issue and print the error, but will restart from the top of the try loop.
Is there a way to continue from where the error occured or will they all need to be seperate?

EDIT::::

I've tried a few ways of formatting this now eg below, but it always goes back to the top input

```
for i in range(branches):
    count += 1
    while True:
        try:
            computer = int(input('{} {} :'.format("Enter number of books for computer of branch", count)))
            bookCount.append(computer)
            try:
                physics = int(input('{} {} :'.format("Enter number of books for physics of branch", count)))
                bookCount.append(physics)
            except ValueError:
                print("Input must be a number:")
                continue
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be a number")
            continue
        if computer < 1:
            print("Number must be at least 1")
        else:
            break
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Yes, you need to put a loop around each input to do what you want to do

Comment: Okay, I've tried a few ways of formatting this now, but it still goes back to the first input every time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have exactly one input inside your try block to do what you want. The best way to achieve this is with a function:

```
def get_input(request_string, count):
    
    while True:
        try:
            value = int(input('{} {} :'.format(request_string, count)))
        except ValueError:
            print("Input must be a number")
            continue

        if value < 1:
            print("Number must be at least 1")
        else:
            return value 

for count in range(branches):
    
    bookcount.append(get_input("Enter number of books for computer of branch", count))
    bookcount.append(get_input("Enter number of books for phsyics of branch", count))
    ...
```

Comment: I think you should make bookcount a dict rather than a list so you can do `bookcount["computer"] = 1`  and you could have your query strings in a similar dict so you can just iterate over that e.g `for each booktype bookcount[booktype] = get_input(booktype)` You should probably also give people a way out of the while() loop, e.g. if the input is zero why not accept it and store it rather than complain?

Comment: Because the breif calls for it to be pointed out as an error unfortunately. Good old uni assignments.

Comment: I know universities can be cut off from the real world, but I would have thought the concept of zero would have reached them by now! A good developer challenges stupid requests! ("What if there are no books?")